# angular - When user view something and reaction with side menu

Tags: angular

I using Angular, Sorry I don't know what keyword for this feature, when user view something, and side menu can reaction now progress, can anyone tell me what keyword for this feature? or how do I achieve it?

Thank any help.

Here are example and screenshots

[example in angular material page](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446171/angular-6-how-to-highlight-element-on-navbar-depending-on-scroll ?

Comment: thank so much, it help full.